# Can a Sorcerer's companion raven speak with everyone?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, sorcerer, familiars, languages

In D&D 3.5, the Sorcerer's companion can be a Raven. In the PHB (p. 52), after the familiars table there is a note that says:

> A raven familiar can speak one language of its master's choice as a supernatural ability.

If I choose the common language, does this mean that after lvl 5 the Raven can speak with everyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the Raven can speak with everyone (in common), but starting at first level, not fifth.
As you quoted it, the Raven obtains a supernatural ability which will allow it to speak one language.
This feature has no relation with Speak with Master, obtained at fifth level.

Speak with Master :

> If the master is 5th level or higher, a familiar and the master can communicate verbally as if they were using a common language. Other creatures do not understand the communication without magical help.

Therefore, at fifth level, in addition to being able to speak with everyone in common, the Raven will also be able to speak with his master, but with a language understandable only for both of them.

Comment: Are you sure about it? There is any specific referenced on manual? This means that that Raven seems little OP for the game.... I mean, you can use it as a spy and message delivered... 

And this also "break" also some spells like "Speak with animals": I mean a sorceres through the raven can speak with all the raven for example.. or not?

Comment: I know no other references that haven't already been quoted. It is an interesting feature indeed, but I wouldn't say OP. Note that if a standard familiar cannot directly talk to other characters, it remains clever enough (6 INT at first level) to convey simple messages by other ways : one peck for yes, two for no, for example. The fact to talk to other member of the species is a familiar feature usually obtained at seventh level (Speak with animals of its kind). The raven indeed gain an alternate way to do it in advance, but it doesn't seem that much OP to me.

Comment: IMHO have a raven that can talk (based on INT) to everyone that can speak common languages is OP, but thanks for your answer; I will check it as a resolved